# How do I benefit from flying Business class out of Montreal with Swiss?

Tags: air-travel, swiss, miles-and-more, yul

For the first time, I got upgraded and will fly out of Montreal in Business class with Swiss. Now obviously I don't know what perks I can expect.

Compared with an Economy class traveller, what benefits can I expect?
For instance, is there any lounge access or priority through Security?

I'm also member of the Miles & More loyalty program but do not have any status other than as a base member with them this year.

Comment: Don't know what Swiss does but taking Air Canada as an example you can expect lounge access, priority boarding, more comfortable/roomy seats

Comment: How did you get upgraded... did you purchase a business class ticket, or get upgraded some other way?

Comment: I purchased an economy and a couple of days before I got an email informing me that I have been upgraded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Swiss webpage on Business Class services](https://www.swiss.com/gb/en/fly/on-board/swiss-business), as a Business class customer you'll have access to the following services:

- Comfortable, reclining seats
- [A larger food selection for meals](https://www.swiss.com/ch/EN/fly/on-board/food-and-beverage/food-and-beverage-business)
- [Better entertainment](https://www.swiss.com/ch/en/fly/on-board/entertainment-on-board#t-page=pane1)
- More luggage allowance
- Access to lounges ([there is a lounge in Montreal](https://www.swiss.com/gb/en/fly/airport/lounges#t-page=pane3) - AC Maple Leaf Lounge, Between gates 52 and 53)
- Priority check-in, baggage drop and boarding
- A toiletry/comfort kit for the flight
- More miles awarder on the flight

Comment: The food selection seems to only applicable when flying out of Zurich, or did i misunderstand the webpage?

Comment: You get the `Swiss speciality` meal only when flying internationally out of Zurich. Probably due to the lack of ingredients elsewhere.

Comment: The Maple Leaf Lounge features free food, drink, alcohol, and WiFi. Also expect better food onboard and goodies like an amenity kit.

Comment: @KateGregory Is right, it was exactly like this

Comment: I'm not sure how Swiss specifically deals with this, but many airlines treat upgrades to business vs. paid business differently for purposes of earning miles. In particular, complimentary upgrades usually earn miles based on the originally-purchased fare class (i.e. economy.)

Answer (score 5):

International business is typically a big step up.  You can check your airplane and seat configuration at websites like this http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Swiss_Airlines/Swiss_Airlines_A330.php 
It looks like Swiss is flying a spiffy A330 with flat bed seats in business from YUL to ZRH.

Meal services has multiple courses, with real cutlery and a nice setup. Unlimited drinks too. That should be fun !

Comment: Thanks, real cutlery and unlimited drinks are also available in Swiss economy.